# simulador de credito

Tags: javascript

Buen día me gustara saber si hay alguna forma de desarrollar un simulador de crédito que me excluya los días inhábiles, sin utilizar una base de datos.

Actualmente trabajo sobre java con esta formula:

```js
monthlyInterest = ((parseFloat(principalAmount)) * (parseFloat(interest) / 100)) / 12;
        pmt = (parseFloat(increment)*parseFloat(PayableYears))+(parseFloat(monthlyInterest) / (1 - Math.pow(1 + ((parseFloat(interest) / 100) / 12), - parseFloat(PayableYears))));
        total = parseFloat(pmt) * (parseFloat(PayableYears));
        /* totalInterest = (parseFloat(total) - parseFloat(principalAmount)); */
        totalInterest = (parseFloat(total) - parseFloat(principalAmount));
        totalivainteres = (parseFloat(iva) * parseFloat(totalInterest));
        ivainteresm = parseFloat(totalivainteres)/parseFloat(PayableYears); 
       totalmasiva = parseFloat(principalAmount)+parseFloat(totalInterest)+parseFloat(totalivainteres)//total  suma de interes + ivainteres + monto inicial 
       pmtmasiva = parseFloat(totalmasiva) / parseFloat(PayableYears);//pago mensial mas iva
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! y como piensas que una computadora sabe cuales son los dias inhabiles????

Comment: Por cierto, **Java != JavaScript**.